# Paper-dropdown-menu : error with Polymer 2.0

Tags: polymer

Hi stackoverflow users,

I want to use the paper-dropdown-menu with polymer 2.0 but when I click on the element, the error below occurs :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'target' of object '#<AnimationPlaybackEvent>'
at b.Animation.<anonymous> (web-animations-next-animation.js:223)
```

I have installed paper-dropdown-menu #2.0-preview.

I tried the very simple example code from the docs:

```
        <paper-dropdown-menu label="Dinosaurs">
        <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" selected="1">
            <paper-item>allosaurus</paper-item>
            <paper-item>brontosaurus</paper-item>
            <paper-item>carcharodontosaurus</paper-item>
            <paper-item>diplodocus</paper-item>
        </paper-listbox>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Could you help me ?

Thank you.

Phil

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a compatibility issue with the web-animations-js library. They released a build on April 13, 2017 that started causing this issue with the 1.x version of paper-drowpdown-menu as well. Anyone doing a bower update after this date will probably see the same behavior until it's resolved.

Adding this to your bower.json file should fix the behavior for you:

"web-animations-js": "web-animations/web-animations-js#2.2.2"

I've filed an issue w/ paper-dropdown-menu regarding this breaking dependency: https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dropdown-menu/issues/241

Comment: It looks like web-animations-js just released a patch that fixes this issue. Doing another bower update will probably resolve this issue for you.  https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js/releases/tag/2.2.4

Comment: Thank you. After the update, the error has disappeared. But nothing happens when I click on the element: the content does not show and there is no error.

Comment: Same with me: no error, but no options are opened on click.

Comment: The link to issue '241' brings us to a pair of demos. Today these demos are broken. But I know how to fix them both: it's needed to add 'slot="dropdown-content" ' instead of ' class="dropdown-content" '. After this fix, both demos will work properly. But, unfortunately, this is not my issue. In my specific app, this does not solve the issue. If I build a new app, paper-dropdown-menu will work as desired. but my specific app is messing up with this control in some way. Hope this comment helps other people.